# How to add different drive ubuntu to BCD manually

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, bootloader

I want to add 12.04 that is in a different drive to my active BCD Store.

What I did is:

- I added a boot sector application pointing to `c:\boot\ubuntu\boot.img` and I only get a black screen with grub>
- I also copied the `mbr` to a file and added to BCD and I get the same results.

I don’t want to use EasyBCD for learning purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I did it.

First, I had to create a `core.img` that point to my drive explicity, Like this:

```
grub-mkimage --output=/tmp/core.img --prefix=\(hd3,1\)/boot/grub --format=i386-pc biosdisk part_msdos ext2
```

Second, I had to concatenate the lnxboot.img and core.img to create a image that can be booted by the boot sector application of the BCD Store.

```
cat /boot/lnxboot.img /tmp/core.img > /tmp/g2ldr
```

Third, I had to copy the g2ldr image to my windows partition and added to my BCD Store with a boot sector application.

Now I can boot Ubuntu from the boot manager of the BCD Store.

Links:

http://blog.mudy.info/2010/08/boot-grub2-stage2-directly-from-windows-bootmgr-with-grub4dos-stage1/

http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Images

Comment: Doesn't work like that for me from Win10, even on an old BIOS machine (no UEFI). It's absolutely necessary to use `grubinst` too, at least version 1.1 to generate a grldr loader () that points to the "g2ldr". Trying to load just the concatenation of lnxboot.img and core.img (tour "g2ldr") directly as a BOOTSECTOR app always fails with error  0xc000007b. But grldr (produced by grubinst 1.1+) works fine loaded as BOOTSECTOR and in turn it can load "g2ldr". That's how it's done in that mudy.info blog, by the way.

Comment: `grubinst` can be a bit hard to find in binary form (version 1.1+) Version 1.3 can be found dropped in the source code of version 1.4... here: https://github.com/chenall/grubutils/blob/master/grubutils/grubinst/grubinst-1.3.zip

Comment: Forgot to add: `-b and -o` options are crucial for `grubinst` in this application, and these flags don't exist pre 1.1. Without them you'd be overwriting your disk MBR instead of producing a grldr file. `grubinst.exe -o -b=g2ldr grldr` produces a grldr that points to g2ldr by name; the latter name "hexedited" in several places in the output file. Some [older] versions of Ubuntu come with a Linux version of grubinst renamed as  `grub-ntldr-img`.